# Why is there no i686 Version of Archlinux bootimage anymore?

Tags: arch-linux

I just tried to run the [latest Archlinux ISO](https://archlinux.surlyjake.com/archlinux/iso/2017.03.01/)  via USB stick on my old Eee PC with i686 processor. However there is no i686 version available in the boot menu. Is this just a bug or on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arch-Linux is phasing out i686 support. The [February 2017 ISO](https://archlinux.surlyjake.com/archlinux/iso/2017.02.01/) is the last one with i686 support. See article on [Arch Linux News - Phasing out i686 support](https://www.archlinux.org/news/phasing-out-i686-support/)